# find all simple Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I need your help to find all simple graphs based the question below,

For n = 3,4, find all simple graphs on G on n vertices such that the degree of each vertex of G is even.

Comment: Start with $n=3$. How many can you get?

Comment: i just find 2. is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (in simple cases) brute force is a possible way to go.
Consider the following picture with all non-isomorphic graphs on 3 and 4 vertices. Then, take your pick.
[image]

You see that your above assertion for $n = 3$ is correct.